# Why are there gaps in my chrome devtools thread when the screen size is large? (react/nextjs)

Tags: performance, google-chrome, next.js, devtools, react-three-fiber

My react app has laggy scroll and animations only when the screen size is large, on medium and below it works fine.
[gaps in thread in devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqIVR.png)
What could be causing this?

Also, I'm using a react three fiber canvas in the background, the page in question is a fixed overlay over the 3D scene

I tried pausing the 3D scene execution with   const DisableRender = () => useFrame(() => null, 1000).

I also tried rendering the page in a new route in next, and the lag is fixed for all screen sizes.